# How to find a semicolon in an infile

Tags: c++

i have a simple program that i am trying to build.  the program is supposed to read characters from a text file, how do I check to see if the character is a space or a semi colon?

```
  char car;
 char car2;

 inFile >> car;
 outFile << "HEADING" << endl;

 while (!car == ';')
```

the above does not seem to work with semi colons.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Can you please explain further? I'm sure there's a better way to do what you're doing.

Comment: I'm certain you meant `(car != ';')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (!car == ';')` is not what you mean. You mean `while (car != ';')` or, if you insist, `while (!(car == ';'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( car != ';' && car != ' ')
{
   //...
}
```

Or

```
while ( inFile >> car && car != ';' && car != ' ')
{
   //...
}
```

Or if there are many characters that you need to check then you can use standard C function `std::strchr` declared in header `<cstring>`

For example

```
const char *delimiters = "; ";
while ( !std::strchr( delimiters, car ) )
{
   //...
}
```

Or if you need to check whether a character is semicolon, space or tab symbol then you can write the following loop

```
while ( car != ';' && !std::isblank( car ) )
{
   //...
}
```

Function `std::isblank` declared in header `<cctype>` and is supported by a C++ 2011 compliant compiler.